# TFS Rest API to get all the projects in a collection shows less

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

When I was trying to get all the projects using the rest API 
https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?api-version=1.0
in my collection on a On-Premise instance it showed me 100 projects where as .Net API and the actual number should be 200.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default is 100 per request, add top=200 to your query string and you will get up to 200 results
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects

Answer (score 2):

At least with my TFS 2015 install, a `$` must prefix the `top` query string key. Example:

```
https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?api-version=1.0&$top=200
```